# Undefined control sequence error using biblatex (\blx@refcontext@context)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors

I was tasked with sifting through a paper and getting rid of all the errors (exciting, I know). The only error I could not figure out is the following:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\blx@tempe @\blx@refcontext@context

l.14

? h
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

?
```

I've searched all over, but could not find a solution that worked. Here is an example of the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee ,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{float} % Allows for control of flat positions
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}    

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\printbibliography

\begin{document}

blablabla here's all the writing and stuff I took out. 
Oh, look, I'm citing some paper \cite{ganan1998generation}

\end{document}
```

For the `bibliography.bib` file, the way the author was calling in references is:

```
@article{ganan1998generation,
  title={Generation of steady liquid microthreads and micron-sized monodisperse sprays in gas streams},
  author={Ga{\~n}{\'a}n-Calvo, Alfonso M},
  journal={Physical Review Letters},
  volume={80},
  number={2},
  pages={285},
  year={1998},
  publisher={APS}
}
```

Other solutions online have stated that the issue comes from calling on multiple citations, but that is not the case here. I commented out all the `\cite{bib1,bib2,etc}` commands throughout the text and still got the same errors.

I should also mention that the undefined control sequence error is being thrown 8 times, all with a different `<argument>` description.

I'm not sure what is happening here and could use a hand. I've tried the solutions from the following pages: [page 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439889/biber-cannot-cite-multiple-references-undefined-control-sequence-argument/440304), [page 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305381/biblatex-empty-bibliography), [page 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89927/begindocument-undefined-control-sequence)

Comment: Wild guess: try deleting the `.aux` file and compile again

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, where can I find that? I'm using Overleaf.

Comment: At the right end of the `Recompile` button there's a sheet-of-paper icon (Logs and output files---click it), and then there is a trash bin icon at the bottom, to the right.

Comment: Done, I'm still getting the same errors

Comment: Ah. `\printbibliography` should go where you actually want the bibliography to appear. In the preamble it's an error.

Comment: I believe that the bibliography located there is a requirement of the paper we're submitting too. Do you mean that it should be located after `\begin{document}`? If so, I tried that and still got the errors. Actually, it turns 14 errors into 97 when I do that.

Comment: jk, you were right. I just reran it after clearing the cache and it worked

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, if you post your answer below, I'll accept it as the answer so you can get the points.

Comment: Yes, if you want the bibliography at the beginning of the document, then move `\printbibliography` after the `\begin{document}`. Nothing that produces typeset output should be before `\begin{document}`. The _number_ of errors is usually meaningless. One error triggers 10 more and so on until TeX just gives up. Usually solving the first will get rid of all others. Okay, I'll write an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error (not terribly clear, I'll give you that) happens because you are using `\printbibliography` in the preamble of the document. The command `\printbibliography`, as the name advertises, prints the bibliography, so it *must* appear after the `\begin{document}` (where you want the bibliography to appear).

That error appears before the usual `Missing \begin{document}` error because `biblatex` does a lot of processing of the bibliography at `\begin{document}`, so some commands (for example the one that raised the error) are not yet defined in the preamble.

Also the bibliography relies a lot on external (what Overleaf calls *cached*) files. Usually a failed compilation will result in an unusable file, which will persist on the error even if you fixed the problem, so it's a good idea to try deleting these files if something's not working.

Comment: I'm wondering if `biblatex` should error more gracefully here. Is there a sort of inverse `\@onlypreamble`? I guess we could also try and guard all the commands that error here, but I'm wondering if that is wort it ...

Comment: @moewe I was wondering about that too. On the one hand, the error is quite cryptic and a clearer message would indeed be helpful. On the other hand, I don't know if this is a terribly common mistake... As for the inverse `\@onlypreamble`, I think you could do `\AtBeginDocument{\newrobustcmd*{\printbibliography}{...}}`

Comment: @moewe Just crossed my mind: a simpler solution than delaying defining `\printbibliography` as an error in the preamble and delaying the definition of `\printbibliography` to `\begin{document}` would be to add something like a `\leavevmode` at the beginning (as long as it doesn't interfere with the output, of course...)

Comment: Mhhh, I was hoping to avoid `\AtBeginDocument` because `biblatex` uses that quite extensively already and it feels wrong to in essence say that all stuff that does typesetting should be defined only then. But then again `\@onlypreamble` is also just a glorified `\AtBeginDocument`... The `\leavevmode` is interesting, but I don't understand all its implications, so I'd rather not try that.

Comment: @moewe It has to be used carefully: `a\par b\par c\par a\par \leavevmode\par c\par`. Perhaps much better would be `\ifx\document\@onlypreamble okay\else error\fi`

Comment: I was also looking at the suggestions from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16295/35864. I'll have a think about this ... still not sure if all the effort is worth it.